# fill in NAs in one dataframe with data from another, two id variables

Tags: r

I've read a lot of questions similar to this, but none of them are similar enough for me to make the answers work. I apologize if this is redundant and I just can't see it.

I have a primary dataset and a backup dataset. When the primary one has an NA, I want to look through the backup, and if there's a value that matches on full.place.name and Year, I want to replace the NA with that value.

`primary` is

```
Year Firearm.Homicide Firearm.Suicide Firearm.Unintentional  full.place.name
2010                0            <NA>                     0 Adair County, KY
2010               10              19                  <NA> Adams County, CO
```

`backup` is

```
Year Firearm.Homicide Firearm.Suicide Firearm.Unintentional  full.place.name
2010               NA               1                     1 Adair County, KY
2010               NA              NA                     0 Adams County, CO
```

What I want is

```
Year Firearm.Homicide Firearm.Suicide Firearm.Unintentional  full.place.name
2010               0               1                     0 Adair County, KY
2010               10              19                     0 Adams County, CO
```

I've tried

```
library(data.table)
setDT(primary); setDT(backup)
primary[is.na(primary$Firearm.Homicide), primary$Firearm.Homicide := backup[backup, primary$Firearm.Homicide, on=c("Year", "full.place.name")]]
```

But that added five columns on to the end, and didn't get any of the values right. I've also tried ifelse statements and FillIn, and I never got close. Here's five rows of data:

```
primary<-structure(list(Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010),
              Firearm.Homicide = c("0","10", "4", "3", NA), Firearm.Suicide = c(NA,"19", "5", "6", 
              NA), Firearm.Unintentional = c("0", NA, NA, "0", "0"), full.place.name = c("Adair County, KY", 
              "Adams County, CO", "Adams County, MS", "Adams County, PA", "Adams County, WI"
              )), .Names = c("Year", "Firearm.Homicide", "Firearm.Suicide", 
              "Firearm.Unintentional", "full.place.name"), row.names = c(NA, 
               5L), class = "data.frame")

backup<-structure(list(Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), Firearm.Homicide = c(NA, 
           NA, 4, 3, 3), Firearm.Suicide = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA), Firearm.Unintentional = c(1, 
           0, 1, NA, NA), full.place.name = c("Adair County, KY", "Adams County, CO", 
           "Adams County, MS", "Adams County, PA", "Adams County, WI")), .Names = c("Year", 
           "Firearm.Homicide", "Firearm.Suicide", "Firearm.Unintentional", 
           "full.place.name"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straight forward solution for this if the two data frames always have the same structure as specified. You can do something like this:
`primary[is.na(primary)] <- backup[is.na(primary)]` if the elements in the table have been mapped to each other beforehand. Here is a way of sorting your data.frame using **dplyr** package supposing your key columns are the "Year" and "full.place.name".

`library(dplyr)
primary <- arrange(primary, Year, full.place.name) %>% select(Year, Firearm.Homicide,Firearm.Suicide, Firearm.Unintentional, full.place.name)
backup <- arrange(backup, Year, full.place.name) %>% select(Year, Firearm.Homicide, Firearm.Suicide, Firearm.Unintentional, full.place.name)`

It might not be the optimum way of doing it but it's easy to understand.

Comment: They aren't mapped to each other now, how could I do that?

Comment: You can sort both data frames by the Keys columns firstly, depending on what they are, here, I guess, should they be "Year" and "full.place.name"?

Answer (score 0):

One option with `data.table` would be using `set`.  The "Firearm" columns in 'primary' are `character` class while the corresponding columns in 'backup' is `numeric`.  So, we need to change the `class` for those columns in "primary" to `numeric` before assigning the `NA` values in the "Firearm" columns in "primary" to corresponding values from the "backup".

After the joining step with `on`, we can loop over the "Firearm" columns, convert the columns to "numeric", replace the "NA" with corresponding values in "i" column and finally `set` the "i" columns to NULL.

```
#joining step
dt <- setDT(primary)[backup, on = c("Year", "full.place.name")]
#identify the Firearm columns with `grep`
nm1 <- grep("^Firearm", names(primary), value=TRUE)
#create a corresponding "i." column names vector from nm1
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
#loop through the columns
for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
  #convert the Firearm columns from primary to `numeric`
  set(dt, i = NULL, j= nm1[j], value = as.numeric(dt[[nm1[j]]]))
  #replace the NA with corresponding values from "i" columns
  set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[nm1[j]]])), j = nm1[j], 
         value = dt[[nm2[j]]][is.na(dt[[nm1[j]]])])
  #remove the i columns by assigning it to NULL
  set(dt, i = NULL, j= nm2[j], value = NULL)
}


dt
#   Year Firearm.Homicide Firearm.Suicide Firearm.Unintentional  full.place.name
#1: 2010                0               1                     0 Adair County, KY
#2: 2010               10              19                     0 Adams County, CO
#3: 2010                4               5                     1 Adams County, MS
#4: 2010                3               6                     0 Adams County, PA
#5: 2010                3              NA                     0 Adams County, WI
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data sets are sorted the same and all names are identical (as per your example), then

```
primary[is.na(primary)] <- backup[is.na(primary)]
primary
#  Year Firearm.Homicide Firearm.Suicide Firearm.Unintentional  full.place.name
#1 2010                0               1                     0 Adair County, KY
#2 2010               10              19                     0 Adams County, CO
#3 2010                4               5                     1 Adams County, MS
#4 2010                3               6                     0 Adams County, PA
#5 2010                3            <NA>                     0 Adams County, WI
```